# How large can the smallest generating set of a group $G$ of order $n$ be?

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $n$ be a natural number. For every group $G$ of order $n$, denote

$d(G)$ : The number of elements of the smallest generating set of $G$

> How large is the maximum possible value of $d(G)$ depending on $n$ ?

If $n$ is a cyclic number, we have $d(G)=1$ for every group of order $n$.
For $n=2p$ , $p$ an odd prime, there are two groups : the cyclic group and the dihedral group with $2$ generators, so in this case the maximum value is $2$.

But I wonder, if the maximal value for $d(G)$ can be determined in general, assuming the factorization of $n$ is known. Is the value known for $n=2048$, for example ?

Comment: For $n=2048$ the maximum value of $d(G)$ is 11, obtained by $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{11}$.

Comment: I expect $Z_2^{11}$ will be the extremal group for order 2048.

Comment: For p-groups, the Burnside Basis Theorem tells you exactly how many generators you need (and the elementary abelian case is indeed the worst case).

Comment: For group of order $p^n$ simply choose elements $a_1,a_2,\dots$ such that $a_k$ does not lie in a subgroup $G_{k-1}$ generated by $a_1,\dots,a_{k-1}$. Then $|G_0|=1$, $|G_k|\geq p|G_{k-1}|$, hence this process stops on at most $n$ steps.

Comment: I am curious why there are 3 votes to close this?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I have to confess that I voted to close, because I just thought it was a well-known problem with the well-known and easy answer $\log_2 n$, described in my answer. I think Geoff's answer has made it into a more interesting question.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: It's maybe also because, while determining the maximum value of $d(G)$ from the factorization of the order $n$ is a delicate and interesting question, the choice of the particularly bad example $n=2^{11}$ shows a certain lack of understanding. (I did not vote to close.)

Comment: @Benjamin me, too. I would like to understand the criteria for so-called good and bad-questions. But, at least, $13$ voters had another oppinion.

Comment: The choice of a p-group shows a lack of knowledge of the Frattini subgroup, but on the other hand the prime factorization is in the problem and then CFSG is needed.

Comment: Anyway I did not intend to criticize the closers although I see my comment could be read that way. I was really just curious since I can see the argument in both directions

Comment: Why should I have asked the question, if I would have known all this ? And the link below I mentioned did not help me either.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

By a Theorem of Guralnick and Lucchini (which does require CFSG), if each Sylow subgroup of $G$ (ranging over all primes) can be generated by $r$ or fewer elements, then $G$ can be generated by $r+1$ or fewer elements. As noted in comments, if $G$ has a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of order $p^{a}$, then $P$ can be generated by $a$ or fewer elements (and $a$ are needed if and only if $P$ is elementary Abelian). Hence if $|G|$ has prime factorization $p_{1}^{a_{1}}p_{2}^{a_{2}} \ldots p_{r}^{a_{r}}$ with the $p_{i}$ distinct primes, and the $a_{i}$ positive integers, then $G$ can be generated by $1 + {\rm max}(a_{i})$ or fewer elements.

(The result attributed to Guralnick and Lucchini was not a joint paper, rather a result proved independently at around the same time: references:

R. Guralnick, "A bound for the number of generators of a finite group, Arch. Math. 53 (1989), 521-523.

A Lucchini: "A bound on the number of generators of a finite group", Arch. Math 53, (1989), 313-317).

Comment: Interesting. I have a related vague question: Assume $G$ embedds in $S_n$. Your answer gives a bound of $n$ on the number of generators. For abelian $G$ this is tight (up to a multiplicative constant, maybe). Is there some family of $G$'s for which we have a better bound? E.g., simple subgroups of $S_n$?

Comment: Simple groups are all $2$-generated.

Comment: @FriederLadisch : The result was proved independently by Guralnick and Lucchini at around the same time, it was not a joint paper  - I had forgotten that myself!

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 25):

The general answer (as a function just of $n$, rather than of its factorization into primes) is $\log_2 n$. It is elementary to prove that this number suffices. Just choose $1 \ne g_1,g_2,g_3,\ldots \in G$ with $g_{i+1} \not\in G_{i} := \langle x_1,\ldots,x_i \rangle$, until $G_k=G$. Since each $G_i <G_{i+1}$ for $i<k$, we have $|G_{i+1}/G_i| \ge 2$, so $|G| = |G_k| \ge 2^k$.

But since an elementary abelian $2$-group requires that number of generators, this bound is best possible.

Comment: .You could add: "... and unlike Geoff's answer, this doesn't require CFSG!"

Comment: What does $CFSG$ mean ?

Comment: @Peter Classification of finite simple groups.

Comment: $\log_2\,n$ is an upper bound, but sometimes one can do better. For instance, if $n$ is a product of distinct primes $p_i$, and no $p_i|(p_j-1)$, then every group of order $n$ is cyclic.

Comment: With all due respect, I do not agree that $\log_2 n$ is "the general answer", since in the question it is assumed that the factorization of $n$ is known, and for example if $n$ is a big prime, then $\log_2 n$ is pretty far of the right answer. $\log_2 n$ is only the answer for $n$ a power of $2$, and also $2$-powers yield the biggest values.

Comment: @Lucia: When $|G| = p_1^{a_1} \dotsm p_k^{a_k}$, then the argument of this answer yields the bound $a_1 + \dotsb + a_k$ (in the worst case, as you say), while Geoff Robinson's answer yields a bound $ 1 + \max\{ a_i\} $.

Comment: @FriederLadisch:  You're right of course!

Comment: @FriederLadisch: It's fair to say that in general, $\log_{2}(n)$ is an upper bound which can't (in general) be sharpened, and is attained infinitely often. Though it is true that we can usually do much better if we know the prime factorization of $n$.

Comment: @FriederLadisch Yes of course you are right! I don't really understand why such a simple and well-known argument merits 18 points.

Comment: I would formulate it in the following way: for groups with at most $n$ elements, maximum is $[\log_2 n]$. While for groups with exactly $n$ elements it is a delicate question. What may be said for sure is that the answer is either $m$ or $m+1$, where $m$ is maximal exponent of primes in factorization of $n$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov and Geoff Robinson: Agreed!

Comment: I looked at this site : http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_2048 and I did not find the upper bound anywhere. And I think I made it quite clear that I am interested in the worst case. I have chosen the example $2048$ because I did not know if the maximum number of generators is known. And the "lack of understanding" is the reason for this question. If I would have known all this, I would not have asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

For natural $n$, let $d(n)$ be the maximum of $d(G)$ as $G$ runs through all groups of order $n$, and let $\nu(n)$ denote the maximal exponent occurring in the canonical prime factorization of $n$. It follows from answers and comments elsewhere in this thread that
$$
d(n)= \begin{cases}
1+\nu(n) & \text{for } n\in S \\
\nu(n)   & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
where $S\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ is a set that we would like to characterize as precisely as possible.

I have now added an [entry A332766](https://oeis.org/A332766) in OEIS listing the members of $S = \{ 6, 10, 14, 18, 21, 22, \ldots\}$. Does anyone have any nontrivial contribution to the characterization of $S$?